# Error msg on linq to dictionary-"an item of the same key value has already been added"

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying do make a collection using linq based on ID which is a GUID.On using dictionary I'm getting error "An item with same key has already been added" Any suggestion?

```
        foreach (Guid i in ar) 
                          { 


               var prod = (from r in datacontext.item_tables's where r.itemID == i select r); 
        Dictionary<Guid, item_tables> tempdata =prod.ToDictionary(s => s.itemID); 
         Facet[] ftemp = new Facet[tempdata.Count]; 
               string s1 = ""; 

               ftemp[0] = new Facet("descriptiob", FacetType.Text, tempdata[i].Description); 

               ftemp[1] = new Facet("date", FacetType.Text, tempdata[i].uploaddate); 


               for (int iv = 0; iv < tempdata.Count; iv++) 
               { 


                   s1 += tempdata[i].ProductName + " \n";  
               } 

               ftemp[2] = new Facet("ProductName", FacetType.Text, s1); 


           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically building your dictionary using this code:

```
datacontext
    .item_tables
    .Where(r => r.itemID == i)
    .ToDictionary(s => s.itemID);
```

The `Where` is filtering the results to where `itemID` is a particular `i` (`Guid`) at a time, but can return zero, one, or more, results. Clearly the error you are getting says that for at least one value of `i` you are getting more than one record returned.

This means the issue either that your database isn't properly normalized or that you've got a logic error in your code.

It sounds like the latter to me.

Further down in your code you have this loop:

```
    for (int iv = 0; iv < tempdata.Count; iv++) 
    { 
        s1 += tempdata[i].ProductName + " \n";  
    }
```

This says to me that you're expecting the `tempdata` dictionary to have more than one value - but you're building the dictionary using `itemID` as the key and this should only put one value in the dictionary based on your query. So something is wrong here in your logic.

Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to do?

---

Based on your comment below (without the clarification from my comment) this appears to be what you want:

```
var query =
    from r in datacontext.item_tables
    group r.ProductName by new
    {
        r.itemID,
        r.Description,
        r.uploaddate,
        r.ItemName,
    };

foreach (var items in query.ToArray())
{
    var f0 = new Facet("descriptiob", FacetType.Text, items.Key.Description);
    var f1 = new Facet("date", FacetType.Text, items.Key.uploaddate);
    var f2 = new Facet("ProductName", FacetType.Text, String.Join("\n", items));
    collection.AddItem(items.Key.ItemName, null, null, f0, f1, f2); 
}
```

Comment: I've a parent table item which has 6-7 child tables holding itemid as foreign key.Each of the item in  item table can be associated to one or more products.So In order to grab all the datas from all the tables I've created a view and that view is item_Tables.Now what I need is I need to grab all the datas based on the id and display all the product name associated to that id.Hope I'm clear.

Comment: @bplvid - So looking at your code again you're accessing the description using `tempdata[i].Description` so this makes makes me think that each product has the same description? Also `uploaddate` & `ItemName` are accessed this way too. This doesn't sound right to me. Can you confirm?

Comment: Hi Enigmativity,MAybe I wasn't clear.Sorry abt that.I have one item which refers to one or more products.But my description,date for each item varies.so I nned to grab description,date,image and all productname associated to one item.

Comment: @bplvid - Then it doesn't sound like you need to group by `itemID`. You could just iterate through `item_tables` and add each to the collection. Is that right?

Comment: i just need to select one id at a time and put the productname in forloop so that i can grab all the productname and other datas like description,date etc.now the difficulty what I'm facing is IF I have 4 productname associated to one item my silverlight pivotviewer shows 4 images which shd't be I need one image with all 4 productname associated to that item.